# hdiutil within "darling" can't do anything but "attach" and "detach". Can it be improved or something else?

Tags: macos, unix, hdiutil

When I run `hdiutil` within [Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/) I get:

```
Darling [/Volumes/SystemRoot/home/user]$ hdiutil
Usage: hdiutil <action>

Possible actions:
    attach [options] <file>
        Mounts a .dmg file <file> and prints the mount locaton
    detach [options] <mount-path>
        Unmounts a .dmg file mounted at <mount-path>
```

I need to run `hdiutil create ...`, is it even possible?

Comment: Since [Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org) is a macOS-to-Linux translation layer, I'm not sure this is the right place to ask. It seems this implementation of `hdiutil` is provided by Darling, not Apple, so you better contact the Darling folks if you need `hdiutil` to be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hdiutil` program you're running is not Apple's - it is a [separate program](https://github.com/darlinghq/darling-dmg/blob/71cc76c792db30328663272788c0b64aca27fdb0/src/main-hdiutil.cpp) made in the Darling project that just happens to be named `hdiutil`.  They're probably hoping to eventually implement the same features as Apple's program, but right now it is limited to only `attach` and `detach` for .dmg files.

When you ask if it is even possible - it depends on what you mean. If you mean "can I get the current hdiutil program to create an image for me" - then the answer is no. If you mean "could a programmer implement the `create` verb if he wanted to?" - then the  answer is yes.

Comment: Very thank! Now it's all clear with darling!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with something else?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/721565/545789